# MultipartEncoder - requests_toolbelt

Tags: python, python-requests-toolbelt

I try send a file to locust, but i need encode the request and, i use MultipartEncoder with this code:

```
multipart_data = MultipartEncoder(
            fields = {
                        "title": "test",
                        "description": "bar",
                        "selfSigned": str(False),
                        "signers":[
                                    {"name":"nn",
                                    "family_name":"nn",
                                    "cellPhonNumber":"+570000000",
                                    "email":"email@email.com",
                                    "type_id":"CC",
                                    "user_id":"000000000",
                                    "fileName":"prueba.pdf"
                                    
                                    }              
                        ],
                        "file": (path, open(path, 'rb'))
                    }
        )
```

but a get the next error.

```
requests_toolbelt/multipart/encoder.py", line 229, in _iter_fields
    file_name, file_pointer, file_type, file_headers = v
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 1)
```

someone know what happens???

Answer (score 0):

If someone need know, the problem is the list and i solve like this

```
fields = {
                        "title": "test",
                        "description": "bar",
                        "selfSigned": str(False),
                        "signers":json.dumps([
                                    {"name":"nn",
                                    "family_name":"nn",
                                    "cellPhonNumber":"+570000000",
                                    "email":"email@email.com",
                                    "type_id":"CC",
                                    "user_id":"000000000",
                                    "fileName":"prueba.pdf"
                                    
                                    }              
                      ]),
                        "file": (path, open(path, 'rb'))
                    }
```